# rented per month postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, date-arithmetic

My task is to count the number of cars rented per month during a specified year.

I have two tables one called cars and one called rental

car table has (car_id, type, monthly_cost)
rental table has (rental_id, car_id, person_id, rental_date, return_date)

The problem is that I can count the number of rentals in a month just on the rental_date,
but that is just giving me new rentals.
For example rental_date: 2020-02-04 and return_date: 2020-05-05, this rental needs to be counted in feb, mars, apr and may.

```
select extract(month from rental_date) as month, count(*)
from rental
where extract(year from rental_date) = 2020
group by extract(month from rental_date);
```

This is my query for counting "new rentals".

Comment: So 30 1-day rentals *of the same car* in January would count as "30".  One 30-day rental would count as "1"?  The question needs more information about how whether you want the number of rentals that overlap in a month, the number of cars rented at all in a month, the maximum number of cars rented in a month, the number of cars that are out on a particular day of the month, or what?

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses `generate_seris()` to generate all starts of months that year, and then brings the table with a `left join` on rental periods that overlap with each month:

```
select d.dt, count(r.rental_id) as cnt_rentals
from generate_series(date '2020-01-01', date '2020-12-01', '1 month') d(dt)
left join rental r 
    on  r.rental_date < d.dt + interval '1 month'
    and r.return_date >= d.dt
group by d.dt
```

Note that this properly handles rentals that cross the beginning of the year, while your original code did not. It also allows months without any rental.